# Declaring Objective-C properties of struct type and initialization

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, properties

I have a singleton class that I use to maintain app state.  Because several different areas utilize it for information, I decided to try to encapsulate my data in the following way.  For example, one class `Signal` checks up on the values of `start` and `end` from my singleton, lets call it `global`.  Rather than defining two properties on this class called `signal_Start` and `signal_End` I was hoping to bury them inside of a struct called `Signal_Status_t`.  And so I have the following struct declaration:

```
typedef struct SignalStatus {
   int start;
   int end;
} Signal_Status_t;
```

Followed by an Objective-C property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic) SampleStatus_t signal_Status;
```

However, when I go to initialize them...

```
self.signal_Status.start = 0;
self.signal_Status.end = 0;
```

I get a compilation error:

> Expression is not assignable.

What I want to do is be able to initialize them in this class as well as be able to set them elsewhere reliably (given that structs are "value types" I worry they won't work properly for this) like: `[Global sharedInstance].signal_Status.start = 100;`.

Hopefully, somebody can help me clarify these issues concerning struct behavior or suggest a better solution if possible that allows me to write code similar to `global.someDomain.someDomainParameter`.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
self->_signal_Status.start = 0
```

or

```
_signal_Status.start = 0
```

(i.e. accessing the instance variable directly), or

```
Signal_Status_t myStatus = self.signal_Status;
myStatus.start = 0;
self.signal_Status = myStatus;
```

if setting both,

```
Signal_Status_t initialStatus;
initialStatus.start = 0;
initialStatus.end = 0;
self.signal_Status = initialStatus;
```

Accessing properties (with self.* ) are method calls; C structures must be set in their entirety, as the setter method argument is the entire structure.  You can combine on the getter methods.  You'll find the same issues trying to set individual values of a UIView's (or NSView's) frame, for example.